# Deploying verticles with a configuration file

Tags: json, configuration-files, high-availability, vert.x

How to write a json configuration file to deploy verticles in vertx dynamically ?

Answer (score 2):

Shameless plug, I wrote a library for that: https://github.com/jponge/vertx-boot

It works on HOCON, which is a superset of JSON.
You write a configuration file in HOCON, where values can be overridden with Java properties, environments variables, alternative configuration files, etc, and the library provides a *main verticle* that spins all declared verticles.

Is it adapted to your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

How I would handling this case would to leverage [Vertx Config](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-config/java/).  I would have an initial verticle that would retrieve the configuration and then I would pull from the config the class names that you want to deploy.

Kotlin Example

```
package com.example

import io.vertx.config.ConfigRetriever
import io.vertx.config.ConfigRetriever.create
import io.vertx.config.ConfigStoreOptions
import io.vertx.core.*
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject
import io.vertx.core.logging.Logger
import io.vertx.core.logging.LoggerFactory
import io.vertx.kotlin.config.ConfigRetrieverOptions

class EntryVerticle : AbstractVerticle()
{
val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EntryVerticle::class.simpleName)

override fun start(startFuture: Future<Void>?) {
    log.info("Started!!")
    val retrieverOptions = ConfigRetrieverOptions()

    //FYI you need to verify that the file is there otherwise this app won't launch.
    //Too much for this example
    val fileConfig = ConfigStoreOptions()
    fileConfig.setType("file").setFormat("json").config = JsonObject().put("path", "/app.json")
    retrieverOptions.addStore(fileConfig)

    val retriever = create(vertx, retrieverOptions)

    retriever.getConfig { config ->

        if(config.succeeded()) {

            val verticles = if (config.result().containsKey("verticles"))
            {
                config.result().getJsonArray("verticles")
            }
            else JsonArray()
            //you would also need to verify this is a string.
            verticles.forEach{className: Any ->
                //example value "com.example.HelloWorldVerticle 
                //full class name
                vertx.deployVerticle(className as String)
            }
            }

    }

    super.start(startFuture)
}
}
```

This was kind of off the cuff but I know you can create verticles from their full name.

There are several other ways you can pull in a configuration besides from the file system.  Its in the doc linked above!!